# How to add crossfiltering across multiple chart types via dash plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

i am trying to apply crossfiltering across two scatter and one parallel coordinates charts. I have got an example to apply crossfiltering across scattered plot, and wanted to modify it for scatter+paralell coordinates, but it does not to what i need. It renders the charts, but crossfiltering is not functioning (functions between scatter plot, but not scatter-parallel coordintates plot). Any thoughts?
Below is the code.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df1

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(id='g1', config={'displayModeBar': False}),  # , figure = fig_s
        className='row'
    ),
    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(id='g2', config={'displayModeBar': False}), # , figure = fig2
        className='four columns'
        ),
    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(id='g3', config={'displayModeBar': False}), # , figure = fig2
        className='four columns'
    ),
], className='row')

### ------------------------------------
### ------------------------------------
### ------------------------------------

def ge_par_cor(df1, fit_col, selectedpoints, selectedpoints_local):

    if selectedpoints_local and selectedpoints_local['range']:
        ranges = selectedpoints_local['range']
        selection_bounds = {'x0': ranges['x'][0], 'x1': ranges['x'][1]}
#         ,
#                             'y0': ranges['y'][0], 'y1': ranges['y'][1]}
    else:
        selection_bounds = {'x0': np.min(df1[fit_col]), 'x1': np.max(df1[fit_col])}
#                             ,
#                             'y0': np.min(df1[y_col]), 'y1': np.max(df1[y_col])}
        

    fig_s = go.Figure(data=
    go.Parcoords(
        line = dict(color = df1['fitness']), #                    colorscale = [[0,'purple'],[0.5,'lightseagreen'],[1,'gold']]),
        dimensions = list([
            dict(range = [2500,4300],
#                     constraintrange = [3000,4300],
                label = 'Bal7_P*', values = df1['Bmn_P']),
            dict(range = [2500,4300],
                label = 'Bal8_P*', values = df1['Bmj_P']),
            dict(range = [5,200],
                label = 'Bal7_PERM', values = df1['Bmn_K']),
            dict(range = [5,200],
                label = 'Bal8_PERM', values = df1['Bmj_K']),
            dict(range = [2,1000],
                label = 'fitness', values = df1['fitness']),
#                 dict(range = [0,1],
#                     label = 'PBU_error', values = df_plot['PBU_error'])
            ])
        )
    )

    fig_s.update_layout(
        plot_bgcolor = 'white',
        paper_bgcolor = 'white'
    )
    
    return fig_s


def get_figure(df1, x_col, y_col, selectedpoints, selectedpoints_local):

    if selectedpoints_local and selectedpoints_local['range']:
        ranges = selectedpoints_local['range']
        selection_bounds = {'x0': ranges['x'][0], 'x1': ranges['x'][1],
                            'y0': ranges['y'][0], 'y1': ranges['y'][1]}
    else:
        selection_bounds = {'x0': np.min(df1[x_col]), 'x1': np.max(df1[x_col]),
                            'y0': np.min(df1[y_col]), 'y1': np.max(df1[y_col])}

    # set which points are selected with the `selectedpoints` property
    # and style those points with the `selected` and `unselected`
    # attribute. see
    # https://medium.com/@plotlygraphs/notes-from-the-latest-plotly-js-release-b035a5b43e21
    # for an explanation
    fig = px.scatter(df1, x=df1[x_col], y=df1[y_col], text=df1.index)

    fig.update_traces(selectedpoints=selectedpoints,
                      customdata=df1.index,
                      mode='markers', 
#                       mode='markers+text', 
                      marker={ 'color': 'rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.7)', 'size': 5 }, 
                      unselected={'marker': { 'opacity': 0.3 }, 'textfont': { 'color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' } }
                     )

    fig.update_layout(margin={'l': 20, 'r': 0, 'b': 15, 't': 5}, dragmode='select', hovermode=False)

    fig.add_shape(dict({'type': 'rect',
                        'line': { 'width': 1, 'dash': 'dot', 'color': 'darkgrey' } },
                       **selection_bounds))
    return fig


# this callback defines 3 figures
# as a function of the intersection of their 3 selections
@app.callback(
    Output('g3', 'figure'),
    Output('g2', 'figure'),
     Output('g1', 'figure'),
    Input('g3', 'selectedData'),
    Input('g2', 'selectedData'),
     Input('g1', 'selectedData')
)
def callback(selection1, selection2, selection3):  # 
    selectedpoints = df1.index
    for selected_data in [selection1, selection2, selection3]:  # 
        if selected_data and selected_data['points']:
            selectedpoints = np.intersect1d(selectedpoints,
                [p['customdata'] for p in selected_data['points']])

    return [get_figure(df1, "Bmj_P", "Bmj_K", selectedpoints, selection1),
            get_figure(df1, "Bmn_P", "Bmn_K", selectedpoints, selection2),
            ge_par_cor(df1, "fitness", selectedpoints, selection3)
           ]

### ------------------------------------
### ------------------------------------
### ------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Below is the sample of df1 table:

```
{'Bmn_P': {0: 2910.0, 1: 3360.0, 2: 3070.0, 3: 3930.0, 4: 3580.0},
 'Bmj_P': {0: 3370.0, 1: 2810.0, 2: 3290.0, 3: 3790.0, 4: 3450.0},
 'Bmn_K': {0: 151.0, 1: 53.0, 2: 87.0, 3: 139.0, 4: 179.0},
 'Bmj_K': {0: 101.0, 1: 181.0, 2: 185.0, 3: 77.0, 4: 43.0},
 'Bmn_H': {0: 14.0, 1: 14.0, 2: 14.0, 3: 14.0, 4: 14.0},
 'Bmj_H': {0: 220.0, 1: 220.0, 2: 220.0, 3: 220.0, 4: 220.0},
 'Qo': {0: 21962.24838819413,
  1: 19061.06202991113,
  2: 19816.201491724027,
  3: 69271.8271469949,
  4: 51387.68989600872},
 'BHP': {0: 2753.0, 1: 2753.0, 2: 2753.0, 3: 2753.0, 4: 2753.0},
 'fitness': {0: 0.1373202267614471,
  1: 0.2282551566658107,
  2: 0.194696411659726,
  3: 0.018317760226405,
  4: 0.0272422482273593}}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of `df1` into your question? you can copy and paste the output from `df1.head().to_dict()`. It will be difficult to debug your code otherwise

Comment: Hi @Derek O. Sure, i have updated my question above with sample from df1 dataframe.
Thank You for looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

you can reference this Parallel Categories Linked Brushing
https://plotly.com/python/parallel-categories-diagram/#parallel-categories-diagram

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).